# Сохранение данных об удалении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ряд элементов, при клике по каждому, оно должно удаляться таким образом, что после перезагрузки страницы, элемент будет отсутствовать. Само удаление происходит 
путём.

```
item.css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

Как это сделать с помощью jQuery?

Comment: Вы можете запоминать в localStorage, например, идентификаторы нужных элементов (правда придется уделить допольнительное внимание их уникальности). И при загрузке страницы скрывать их, получая набор селекторов из localStorage